# BotBuilder async counter implementation with Task not working

Tags: c#, async-await, botframework

I'm trying to make my Bot more fluid by holding a response until the messages become sparse.

My idea was simple: every time I receive a message, I spawn a delayed task to inform the future me whether I should respond the recent activity or not.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

namespace GupyInterviewBot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class InterviewDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        private int _patience = 0;

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            _patience = 0;
            context.Wait(PatientReadAsync);
        }

        public async Task PatientReadAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IActivity> awaitable)
        {
            var activity = await awaitable;
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                HoldOn();
                context.Wait(PatientReadAsync);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync("My patience is running out: " + _patience);
                context.Wait(PatientReadAsync);
            }
        }

        private void HoldOn(int seconds = 3)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                _patience += 1;
                await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000);
                _patience -= 1;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, the `_patience` counter is only increasing and never decreasing I have no idea why. I posted this question without mentioning the framework, but after trying to find a MWE with a Console Application everything worked. Now I believe there's something related to the way the framework preserves state, but I'm not sure.

You can attest that `_patience` is only increasing by sending a few messages and then send some `Ping` activities in the Bot Emulator.

Comment: Is the line `_patience -= 1;` ever reached (put a break point on it)? Also this is not thread safe, for that you should use `Interlocked`

Comment: Whats seconds set to? Could be a crazy long delay so _patience -= 1 never hits. Do what @lgor said, or even a Debug.WriteLine(" some messag"); after the Delay.

Comment: It is being hit, after steping into it: _patience decreases by one. The next time this runs, it is as if it had not decreased.

Comment: Then you should show the rest of your code that is calling this because it is probably an issue with class initialization, proper scoping, or maybe even a race condition.

Comment: _patience is a class attribute, and this task is spawned inside a method. I echo the patience on every request and I can see it is increasing there. I don't modify it anywhere else either. The code is quite big, I'll cut the irrelevant parts.

Comment: "*_patience is a class attribute*" It [can't be a atribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x6cd29c(v=vs.110).aspx) it makes no sense in this context. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch that re-creates the problem and post that in your question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sorry, I'm still used to python terminology. Is a field. I'm having trouble coming up with a MWE because it works fine on a Console Application.

Comment: I assume this is some kind of asp.net project. Create a minimal ASP.net project that recreates it and post the relivant parts here.

Comment: Heres the MWE (not so minimum because of the framework), but now I have a suspect root cause: maybe the state is being serialized before the decrement runs, and when it is deserialized from disk it reverses the change. I don't know much about the internals of the framework though, so I'd need opinions.

Comment: Do you intend HoldOn() to return immediately to PatientReadAsync(), or to only return after the delay?

Comment: @sellotape I don't care about its return, I just want to decrement after the delay. That's a misnomer, I guess.

Comment: Then it won't do that.  It will queue the task and return immediately.  I'll suggest a change in an answer.

Comment: Any reason you cannot use the out-of-the-box state mechanism coming with the Bot?

Comment: @EzequielJadib It could only be ignorance. How would the state api help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
private async Task HoldOnAsync(int seconds = 3)
{
    _patience += 1;
    await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000);
    _patience -= 1;
}
```

and change

```
HoldOn();
```

to

```
await HoldOnAsync();
```

`Task.Run()` just queues the task and returns immediately.  So it's probably working but your increments are winning the race.

Comment: BTW this was based on your response to my comment before you edited it.  Let me know if it's not working based on your revised comment and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that answer. I don't think this is the problem, but I do think this is the only way to do it to avoid a race condition between the delay and the serialization (unless I lock it).

Comment: It's very easy to use Interlocked.Increment()/Decrement() - perhaps try those.  Also write some debug messages when it increments and decrements to see whether you're just calling HoldOn() more frequently than every 3 seconds.  If you are, the increments will win.